# SSL not working Apache, mod already enabled ports already open

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, https, google-cloud-platform, lets-encrypt

I have an issue in production server debian 10 in google cloud platform.
SSL not working Apache but these conditions are already fulfilled:

- mod ssl already enabled
- firewall GCP already opened.
- already listen to 443 in ports.conf
- port 443 already open, can be telnet from inside (localhost) or outside (another server/pc)
- certbot already published
- apache configuration vhost already correct (in my opinion)

So the weird things is, I create this VPS based on image previous VPS that https apache already working.
let say the issue is in server C.
First time I have Server A and https works, I duplicate the image and make Server B also https works.
Then I duplicate image from Server B become Server C, but https not working.

The spec are:

- GCP Cloud compute
- apache 2.4
- cloudflare free plan (also works in server A and B)
- debian 10

Is there anything step that I missed? Thank you

EDIT:

this is the error from Chrome: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

and this is from firefox: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

result for curl myserverIP -sv:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: MyServerIp/
*   Trying MyServerIp...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to MyServerIp (MyServerIp) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: MyServerIp
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 11 Nov 2020 03:09:31 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
< Last-Modified: Sun, 20 Sep 2020 11:53:07 GMT
< ETag: "3ee-5afbd609741c1"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 1006
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Type: text/html
<
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <title>MISTAR on Google Cloud</title>
                <link rel="icon" href="favicon_exi.png" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
        </head>
        <style>
        html, body {
        height: 100%;
        }
        body {
        margin: 0;
        }
        .flex-container {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        }
        .row {
        width: auto;
        /*border: 1px solid blue;*/
        }
        .flex-item {
        /*background-color: tomato;*/
        padding: 5px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 10px;
        line-height: 20px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 2em;
        text-align: center;
        }
        </style>
        <body>
                <div class="flex-container">
                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="flex-item"><img src="mistar-main.493699d8.png" height="60px" /></div>
                                <div class="flex-item"><img src="cloud-logo.svg" width="280px" /></div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </body>
</html>* Connection #0 to host MyServerIp left intact
```

the result of openssl:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140205097211008:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 313 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work? What errors do you see? Show us the output of `curl -sv` or `openssl s_client`.

Comment: oh okay sorry, will edit the question for the errors and the curl and openssl output

Comment: `curl -sv` for the HTTPS would be more relevant.

Comment: what do the logs of apache say ? From the output of ```openssl s_client``` - could it be, that apache doesn't find the SSL certificates at the path configured ?

Comment: There is no logs after openssl s_client @Martin , I already edit the question about the openssl sclient result

Comment: you missunderstood me: The results you posted looked like apache didn't find the correct certificate, that's why I suggested to look in the system logfiles... Issue a restart of apache and see if it throws any errors / warnings in the syslog...

Comment: How does the virtualhosts look like? Have you specified the correct certificates? Have you dubblechecked the ServerName and ServerAlias part? 
You have to provide more information about the server,

Comment: @Martin after restart service apache2 syslog is no error or warn: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server. Reloading The Apache HTTP Server., but in apache2 error log there is warn like this:  [ssl:warn] [pid 16606] AH01909: servername.asia-southeast2-a.c.stoked-castle-id.internal:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the

Comment: you have an let's encrypt certificate, but the servername (from the warning above) ends in .internal ? Check that the path to the certificates is correct and that these certificates exist (```openssl x509 -in <file> -text -noout``` to verify that it is correct), check that the ServerName setting is correct... we cannot help you more than that without more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the comment the help me debugging, the ssl now working after I change the certificate from snake oil to new generated in default-ssl file inside sites-available.